# Determining What Text Editor to Use By Default Based on Site Location in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, nodes, input-formats, users

Okay, so this is something I've been wrestling with for a while. We have several different types of users on our site. For example: Bloggers, Writers (for actual articles), editors, and ordinary users that don't have access to writing blogs or articles.

When a user that falls under the Blogger/Writer/Editor role goes to post on our forum section, he/she is presented with the option of choosing what text editor to use.

What I'd like to do is set things up so that a plain text editor is used by default for the forum, and that a WYSIWYG editor is used for articles and blogs. I don't want to present the user with a choice as to which one to use. It should be a straightforward process.

So what do I need to do in order to define the default text editors?

Answer (score 2):

I use the [WYSIWYG module](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) to define different profiles for each text input format and the [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module to define which roles get what input formats on which content types.